# What is inherited in Maven projects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

When making a parent Maven project, what does the child projects inherit?

After what I understand groupId is inherited by the parent project too, but where can I actually see that in documentation?

This is all thats listed (after what I found).

```
dependencies
developers and contributors
plugin lists
reports lists
plugin executions with matching ids
plugin configuration
```

http://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Almost anything that has been specified in a parent is inherited by the child. It's actually better to ask "What is not inherited by a child project in Maven?" as that would probably be a shorter list.

Examples of things not included in the list at [maven inheritance docs](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) (which you listed in your question) that are also inherited would be `scm` tag, `distributionManagement` tag, and any declared properties (I use this quite a bit for setting default character encoding).

The certain way to find out if a child project has inherited something from a parent is to run the [help:effective-pom mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) on the child project. This will show you the complete effective pom at build time for that project which will have inherited elements included. Example invocation below.

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

Some IDEs also have tools for viewing the 'effective pom' of a project (i.e. M2E eclipse plugin).

Comment: "licenses", "issueManagement", "properties", "url" and "build" are also inherited, but strangely "profiles" [isn't](http://www.dashbay.com/2011/03/maven-profile-inheritance/).